# Karma Start, Karma Init, npm test not exiting?

Tags: macos, npm, jasmine, karma-runner

Is it normal behavior for `karma start`, `karma init`, `npm test` to not exit after running?  I want to run additional commands but I have to open another window to do it.

[image]

Comment: to run all test cases at one go, this process terminates after all cases are done - npm run test-headless

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try below config parameter for Karma..

**singleRun**

Type: Boolean

Default: false

CLI: --single-run, --no-single-run

Description: Continuous Integration mode.
If true, Karma will start and capture all configured browsers, run tests and then exit with an exit code of 0 or 1 depending on whether all tests passed or any tests failed.

Source - http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html